# unit test with AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo got "IllegalStateException: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock"

Tags: junit, android-testing, robolectric

android app using the ShadowGoogleApiAvailability

```
object Util {
    @JvmStatic
    @WorkerThread
    fun getAdsClientInfo(context: Context): AdvertisingIdClient.Info? {
        val isGPAvailable = 
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)
        return if (isGPAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context) //<=== throws
        } else null
    }
}
```

in the test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TestAds{

    public Application application;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getAdsClientInfo() throws Exception {

        final ShadowGoogleApiAvailability shadowGoogleApiAvailability
                = Shadow.extract(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance());
        final int expectedCode = ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
        shadowGoogleApiAvailability.setIsGooglePlayServicesAvailable(expectedCode);

        AdvertisingIdClient.Info info = Util.getAdsClientInfo(application);
        ......
    }
}
```

It got `"IllegalStateException: Calling this from your main thread can lead to deadlock"`.

How to test the function which internally called `AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple run: "AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo" on IO thread.

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo()
    
}
```